# same type of some file not writing properly - data loss

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ftp

I am using C#,compact framework 3.5 developed the mobile application. I am writing the stream of data as xml file and send the file to FTP server.90% of files are perfectly transferred to server without data loss,however remaining 10% files are loss some data,some file have loss entire data and an empty file is saved in FTP server.Please below code

```
stream = new MemoryStream();
var uriWithoutScheme = new Uri(ApplicationGlobals.Instance.DropFolder).Host;
var ftp = new FTP(uriWithoutScheme);
ftp.Connect(ApplicationGlobals.Instance.UserName, ApplicationGlobals.Instance.Password);

docEventFile.Save(stream);   //save the stream

ftp.SendFile(stream, string.Format("{0}.xml", Util.GetFileName(xmlFileName))); //sent the stream of data to FTP server and rename the file
ftp.Disconnect();
```

Above is the code which save the file and send the same to FTP server.I want to know why some data loss and how to rectify this.

Need help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided doesn't show the interesting part: the `FTP` class. "Data loss" sounds weird because FTP is based on [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) which is designed to be reliable, to prevent this situations.

Anyway, I recommend you not to reinvent the wheel, and use a well tested library.
There are many `FTP` libraries out there. I personally use [Alex FTPS Client](http://ftps.codeplex.com/) library. 
It provides convenient `FTP` interface, and works perfectly for both `FTP` and `FTPS`